# Can I pass a String into a function and call the string in referencing Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Please can someone tell me if it's possible to do something like this in android studio x Firebase?

```
public Class search(String item){
    private class GetXYZ implements "something" {
        private static final String TAG = "the tag";
        private DatabaseReference refR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("FRUITS").child("item");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. You need to pass `item` object of type String as an argument in your `DatabaseReference` but you must pass it directly into `child()` method without quotation marks like this:

```
private DatabaseReference refR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("FRUITS")
    .child(item);
```

As you can probably see, the last child does not have quotation marks anymore. If you use `child("item")` it means that you are passing the String **`item`** as an argument and not the value of `item` object which is of type String.

Comment: sure, just did.